# Difference between two predict functions

Tags: r

experts!

I was testing a logistic regression model on a training dataset. I knew that the "Predict" function can tell me the probability (type="response") of a unique event happening( In this case, an employee left the company).

I was also aware that a new package called "Tidypredict" released in January 2019, which also predicts the probability of an event happening at 95% interval.

When I tried these two different methods, it shows different probabilities for the same employee.

I researched the topic. It seems that the best timing to use "Predict" function is when the final result is already known. Because we can compare and find out how accurate the model would be.

"Tidypredict" function is used when the outcome is unknown. Could anyone please tell me what the difference is? 
Here is the information readily available: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidypredict/tidypredict.pdf

### Predict:https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html

```
Here is the results for anyone interested: 
test model:         
1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.6633092 0.2440294 0.2031897 0.9038319 0.8374229 0.1735053 
Tidypredict:

    Age         Los Gender Minority test.model       fit
1 xx.xx ThreeToFive   Male Minority  0.6633092 0.7116757
2 xx.xx   ZeroToOne   Male Minority  0.2440294 0.6834286
3 xx.xx   ZeroToOne Female Minority  0.2031897 0.6303713
4 xx.xx TentoTwenty   Male Minority  0.9038319 0.6963801
5 xx.xx ThreeToFive   Male Minority  0.8374229 0.8658365
6 xx.xx   ZeroToOne Female Minority  0.1735053 0.5840209



      #logistic model# 
model1=glm(Leave~.,family="binomial",data=train)
       #Predict function# 
    test.model<-predict(model1,newdata=test1,type="response")
      #Tidypredict function#
       emp_risk<-test1%>%
       tidypredict_to_column(model1)
```

Comment: Are `df` and `test1` the same dataframes? Maybe this is why you are getting different results.

Comment: I just updated the code, sorry for the confusion. I was trying back and forth and forgot to update the posting here.

Comment: Can you also post the output of both the results please

Comment: I just did. the result is available in the code section now.

Comment: Looks like the only difference is that tidypredict returns a dataframe with both the input values and the output prediction whereas predict only give you the prediction. I didn't form the same conclusion as you did regarding when to use them. Looks to me that the `tidypredict` just uses the logistic regression model to pipe the  prediction operation into back into the dataframe with the newdata.

Comment: Thank you 42 for the explanation. But why we see two different values? Wouldn't it     be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem - here's a reproducible example illustrating that the predictions from `predict()` match those of `tidypredict_to_column()`. My advice - dig into a specific example that doesn't match and figure out the difference. If you post a reproducible example, you'll get more specific help:

```r
library(titanic)
library(dplyr)
library(tidypredict)
d <- titanic_train
mod <- glm(Survived ~ Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp + Parch, data = d, family = "binomial")

d <- d %>% tidypredict_to_column(mod)
d$fit2 <- predict(mod, newdata = d, type = "response")
summary(d$fit - d$fit2)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
#>       0       0       0       0       0       0     177
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Chase! I realized what the problem is in my model. I should not have to level the LOS categorical variable. Once I removed the column, then the two values become the same.